# android libgdx bitmap fonts turn to black rectangles after a while

Tags: android, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

I'm using **gdx-freetype** library in android to generate **BitmapFont** from TrueType font which is in assets/fonts/arial.ttf
This is the way I use to show some text on screen

```
generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/arial.ttf"));
font30 = generator.generateFont(60 , "ConectigTsrv" , false);
generator.dispose();    
Label l = new Label("Connecting to server...", new LabelStyle(font30 , Color.BLUE));
l.setX(400 - l.getWidth()/2f);
l.setY(480 - l.getHeight() - 10);
stage.addActor(l);
```

text will be printed to screen very well

[image]

But after a while or when I push Home button and then come back to application all characters turn to black rectangles

[image]

Any idea about whats going on?

Comment: I would do a debug to see exactly what happens when you press any of the buttons

Comment: I suppose it's bitmap's fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the textures created by FreeTypeFontGenerator were not managed until this recent [commit](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/ddc853b124707171261ec5f5c89cafa648be7841). The fact that textures are unmanaged means that they have to be reloaded following a loss of the OpenGL context, which occurs in scenarios such as the one you described.

If you upgrade libgdx to the [latest nightlies](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/) then the problem will probably go away.

For more information, the problem with unmanaged textures is described very well in [this article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1073).

Comment: yesssss I used last nightly build and everything is fine.I just read the article you mentioned thank you.but The version I was using was 0.9.9.Commit is done after this version isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still having this problem. Using LibGDX 1.9.2, I had this problem as well:
Run the game, navigate 'back' to Android home screen, go back to the game and fonts would be black rectangles.

Turned out I was loading all textures in a static way, which  only loads them once at game start and never again:

```
//THIS IS WRONG
public class Styles {
    public static final BitmapFont HEADER_FONT;
    public static final FreeTypeFontGenerator _freeTypeFontGenerator = ...

    static {
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter params = ...
        HEADER_FONT = freeTypeFontGenerator.generateFont(params);
    }
}
```

This causes trouble when the game is reloaded in memory. As far as I understand, the final fields now refer to non-existent texture data. To fix that, I got rid of the final properties and load them in the create() function, recreating all assets each time the game is reloaded in memory:

```
public void onCreate() {
    Styles.loadAssets();
}
```

And in Styles:

```
//STATIC RESOURCES CAN CAUSE TROUBLE, KEEP IT IN MIND
public class Styles {
    public static BitmapFont HEADER_FONT;
    public static FreeTypeFontGenerator FONT_GENERATOR = ...

    public static void loadAssets() {
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter params = ...
        HEADER_FONT = FONT_GENERATOR.generateFont(params);
    }
}
```

I prefer my read-only assets to be static to be memory friendly. However, the use of static resources may still create problems I'm not aware of, as [per the manual](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager).